# A problem involving mathematical indcution

Tags: induction

$G(0) = 2$
$G(1) = 5$
$G(k) = 5  G(k-1) - 3  G(k-2)$ if $k \geq 2$

$H(0) = 0 $ 
$H(1) = 1  $
$H(k) = 5 H(k-1) - 3  H(k-2)$ if $k \geq 2$

Functions $G$ and $H$ are natural numbers.
Show that for all $k \geq 1, G(k) = (13  H(k-1) + 5  G(k-1))/2$

I started by saying:
Let $P(k)$ be the mathematical statement: $G(k) = (13   H(k-1) + 5   G(k-1))/2$

For the base case, I found $P(1)$:
$G(1) = (13   H(1-1) + 5   G(1-1))/2$ which gives $5=5$ so it is correct.

This is where I'm having trouble. I know I have to show $k+1$ like so:
$G(k+1) = (13  H((k+1)-1) + 5  G((k+1)-1)$ but I don't really know where to start.

I tried by making $H(k)$ and $G(k)$ and then replacing them with their definitions but I don't see how that helps me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please include all necessary details in the question, in stead of providing a link. Also, your question is unclear. What does it mean to *"show that for all $k$'s, $G(k)$."*? And what is $P(k)$?

Comment: I edited, hopefully this is better..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use strong induction, we shall use
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_{k-1}=\frac{13H_{k-2}+5G_{k-2}}{2} \\ 
G_{k}=\frac{13H_{k-1}+5G_{k-1}}{2}. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_{k+1}=5G_k-3G_{k-1} &=& 5\frac{13H_{k-1}+5G_{k-1}}{2} -3\frac{13H_{k-2}+5H_{k-2}}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=& 5\frac{13H_{k-1}+5G_{k-1}}{2} +\frac{13}{2}(H_k-5H_{k-1})+\frac{5}{2}(G_k-5G_{k-1}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=& \frac{13}{2}H_k+\frac{5}{2}G_k. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Just to make sure, are my other steps correct or did I make a mistake before?

Comment: You showed the inductive hypothesis for $P(1)$, you will also need to show it for $P(0)$, in order to verify the base cases for strong induction. In your question, you wrote $G(k+1) = (13  H((k+1)-1) + 5  G((k+1)-1)\color{red}{/2}$, you could have simplified this to $G(k+1) = (13  H(k) + 5  G(k))/2$ ?

Comment: Yeah i wasnt sure for the second base case since k$\ge$1, I thought maybe I didn't have to show 0. I knew for the simplifying part, I just wanted to show the replacement being made for all the k's. If I do P(0), won't I get H(-1) and G(-1) which I do not have the answers to?

Comment: Could I do the base case P(2) instead?